# Python index error out of range

Tags: python-2.7

I need allocate seats in alternate for different department but when I try to do I'm  getting errors.

Below I have pasted the code:

```
#matrix for dept1
X = [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777 ,888, 999, 123, 234,345]
#matrix for dept2
Y = [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999,9876, 8765,7654]
#empty class room which consist of 18 students
class_room = [[0,0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0]]


ca = 0

pa = 0

print 'combining dept1 and dept2 in alternative manner'


for i in range(5):

    for j in range(25):

        if j%2 == 0:
            class_room[i][j] = X[pa]
            pa += 1
        else:
            class_room[i][j] = Y[ca]
            ca += 1

print class_room

#error - Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "C:\Users\SONY\workspace\mine\taest3.py", line 24, in <module>
#   class_room[i][j] = X[pa][pa]
#IndexError: list index out of range
```

kindly help me to rectify and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop `for j in range(25)`, but you have nothing that's 25 elements long. Instead, do this:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):  # DIFFERENT
        if (5 * i + j) % 2 == 0:  # ALSO DIFFERENT
            class_room[i][j] = X[pa]
            pa += 1
        else:
            class_room[i][j] = Y[ca]
            ca += 1
```

Note that this will introduce a *new* IndexError because you have 25 classrooms and only 24 entries in `X` and `Y` combined. Add another element to `X` and the code will run.

Comment: Happy to help. If this was especially helpful, I encourage you to upvote it.